# Setup ordering in priority blocking queue

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue

I have a `PriorityBlockingQueue` in which I am adding `SocketHolder`. And let's say current datacenter where this code is running is `abc`, we have three datacenters `abc`, `def` and `pqr`.

```
private static final PriorityBlockingQueue<SocketHolder> liveQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();

for (SocketHolder socket : listOfSockets) {
    liveQueue.add(socket);
}
```

Now what I need to do is:

- I have to setup some sort of ordering on `liveQueue` so that all `SocketHolder` whose datacenter is `abc` (which is current datacenter where the code is running), they should be at the top so which means when we retrieve it from this `liveQueue` all `SocketHolder` with `abc` datacenter should come out first and then later on all other `SocketHolder` with other dc's. Similarly for cases where current datacenter is either `pqr` or `def`.

This is my `SocketHolder` class that implements Comparable interface and what I need to do in my `compareTo` method so that at the top of `liveQueue` (after adding elements to it) we have all `SocketHolder` whose datacenter are current datacenter and then followed by other datacenter in which I have no priority.

Here is how I did: The live datacenter will be assigned priority 1, and the other datacenters priority 2. The queue will process the lowest priority first.

```
public final class SocketHolder implements Comparable<SocketHolder> {
   private final Socket socket;
   private final Datacenter dc;
   private final Context context;
   private final int priority;

   public SocketHolder(Socket socket, Datacenter dc, Context context) {
      super();
      this.socket = socket;
      this.dc = dc;
      this.context = context;
      this.priority = this.dc.name().equalsIgnoreCase(Utils.CURRENT_DATACENTER.get().name()) ? 1 : 2;
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(SocketHolder o) {
       return Integer.compare(this.priority, o.priority);
   }
}
```

I wanted to see if this is the right way to do it or is there is any better way.

Answer (score 1):

You currently couple your SocketHolder class with the environment it exists in, as you have the comparable interface implemented in SocketHolder which in turn uses `Utils.CURRENT_DATACENTER.get().name()`. I don't think that this is a good idea, as this dependency seems unnecessary and makes isolated testing difficult. (Or in other words: bad gut-feeling ;-))

Suggestion: as you set up your priority queue in a specific environment, and at that place it is probably OK to know the environment. So, use the constructor for priority queue where you pass a Comparator explicitly, and write a comparator which basically does the same as the compareTo-method you have in your SocketHolder right now.